# Ghotiy spelling

Tags: wordplay, english

As some of you likely know, [ghoti](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghoti) is an interesting spelling of the word `fish`.

Using:

```
the "gh" from "tough"
the "o" from "women",
and the "ti" from "nation"
```

This is a rather ghotiy way to spell the word. But in the same spirit, what common phrase is spelled below?

**ugh theighmolo**

Please mention each sound and what word it is taken from (there may be more than one word that fits!)

Hint:

> The "u" and "gh" in "ugh" are taken from separate sources.

Comment: This page may come in handy: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_orthography#Spelling-to-sound_correspondences

Comment: Given the three answers, the question could be _what phrase does it **not** spell_?

Comment: @PålGD Strangely enough, I can't get it to spell "ugh theighmolo"...

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I think it's

> egg timer

Explanation:

> <u> denotes /ɛ/ in *bury* (at least in some dialects). (Hat-tip to Miles' Wikipedia-link for this one.)
>  <gh> denotes /g/ in *ghost*.
>
>  <th> denotes /t/ in *thyme*.
>  <eigh> denotes /aɪ/ in *height*.
>  <m> denotes /m/ in *timer*.
>  <olo> denotes /ɝ/ in *colonel*. (Technically *egg timer* ends in /ɚ/ rather than /ɝ/, but I think it's close enough.)

Answer (score 183):

It's pronounced

> 

Using these "sounds":

> `U: as in *guard*.`
> `G: as in *reign*.`
> `H: as in *hour*.`
>
> `T: as in *ballet*.`
> `H: see above.`
> `E: as in *active*.`
> `I: as in *friend*.`
> `G: see above.`
> `H: see above.`
> `M: as in beginning of *mnemonic*.`
> `O: as in *leopard*.`
> `L: as in *salmon*.`
> `O: see above.`

(Examples mostly taken from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silent_English_alphabet).)

Comment: Ok +1 because this is hilarious. But that wasn't what I was looking for.

Comment: ...I kept clicking the spoiler even after reading the explanatory text.

Comment: I kept trying after reading your comment, @Deusovi, because I thought my phone was rendering something wrong.  **facepalm**

Comment: I think you'll find that the second occurrence of gh is gh as in dau**gh**ter.

Comment: I'm not English so I didn't know this common phrase :-(

Comment: TIL you can spell Finnish smalltalk in English.

Answer (score 18):

It is pronounced

> OFF TIMER

Using:

> the "ugh" from co**ugh**
>  the "th" from **Th**aïs
>  the "ei" from h**ei**ght
>  the "gh" from slou**gh**
>  the "m" from **m**agic
>  the "olo" from "c**olo**nel"

Comment: You could also combine the "ei" and "gh" sections.

Comment: @f'' This is true. :) Hmmm... *maybe* it's true. The "gh" might be creating the glottal stop in height.

Comment: The glottal stop is just an allophone of /t/. Compare "sight" with "site" (they should both rhyme with "height").

Comment: I think the second word might be tamer not timer. As in sl**eigh**. But can't figure out the first.

Comment: "cough" is pronounced "coff", so that makes "ugh" = "ff".

Comment: ugh is sometimes pronounced "you". Can't think of any examples. ;-)

Comment: +1 This works pronunciation-wise but there's a more common phrase I had in mind.

Comment: I've never heard of the example word for the second entry in the second spoiler box. Clearly it's a proper name, but it must for something that doesn't seem to appear often or ever in the news sources I access or entertainment that I enjoy.

Comment: @ToddWilcox Thaïs was a famous Greek hetaria, and the name of two songs on This Mortal Coil's album *Filigree & Shadow*.

Comment: @Lexible I find it pretty funny that I also have never heard the word "hetaria" before. My college degree is in Mathematics, so that might account for my ignorance. (PS, I also haven't heard the word "hetaira" before, which I'm pretty sure is the word you meant.) Ah, my best friend is a professor of Classics and Sexuality studies, but he's a Latinist, not a Hellenist, so I've probably heard the ancient Latin equivalent before.

Comment: @ToddWilcox . . . o 0 O (am trying to think of a famous manifold projection named "Thaïs" ;).

Comment: @Lexible Pretty close though. _hint_ :)

Answer (score 4):

Maybe

> a typo? (This phrase may not be so common, but at least is related to spelling)

Using

> "u" as in "support"
>  "gh" as in "weight" (silent)
>  "th" as in "Thames"
>  "ei" as in "height"
>  "gh" as in "hiccough" (pronounced like "hiccup", now obsolete)
>  "m" as in "mnemonics" (silent)
>  "o" as in "go"
>  "l" as in "chalk" (silent)
>  "o" as in "leopard" (silent)

Comment: I'm not sure that I agree on your assessment of some of those "silent" letters. "chalk" vs "chak" have different pronunciations; the 'l' changes the pronunciation, making it not silent.

Comment: "tap" vs. "tape" the 'e' changes the pronunciation, but wouldn't you still call it a silent 'e'? At least that's what I was taught in grade school.

Comment: @Dane Andersen I do agree with you. Silent letter is a letter which isn't pronounced, in my humble opinion

Comment: ... I distinctly pronounce the 'l' in 'chalk'. Am I just weird?

Comment: @Amadeus9 I'm kinda confused who doesn't. "Chock?"

Comment: I have never pronounced the "l" in "chalk", or heard anyone pronounce it. It sounds strange to me to pronounce it that way. (I was born and raised in the northeast US.)