# Ghotiy® Puzzle #1

Tags: wordplay, english

Considering how @Chowzen is starting a [new puzzle series](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/63209/43256) that’s pretty amazing, why not bring back one from last year?

For this puzzle’s inspiration, check [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/32278/43256) question out.

What does the following sentence spell?

> Reut I Eighth Ng Mi

*I will post a hint a day after these two hints for every day this question is not answered!*

Hint #1:

> The spaces don't really matter, and some words have one part taken from one "word" above and another part taken from the next "word."

Hint #2:

> Do not be offended at my profanity, and don't be afraid to post your answer XD

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe this is a possible though unlikely solution.

As

1. > "R eu" becomes `Are you`
2. > "t I" becomes "ti" which becomes `sh` like in "staTION"
3. > This one is somewhat of a jump but "eigh" becomes "i" like in "height" and "i" can also be pronounced like the `i` in "hit"
4. > "th" becomes "ti" like in "thyme". `ti` can also be pronounced like in "tick"
5. > "ng" becomes `ng` like in sing
6. > "mi" becomes `me`

Putting everything together, we get

> Are you shitting me.

Comment: Congrats! I took the previous puzzle a little farther by going farther with the pronunciation a.k.a “ti” can be pronounced two ways, but you still got it! I’ll wait a bit before accepting okay?

Comment: @NL628 you know I’m using your computer right now, don’t you?

Comment: But this is like personal stuff so let’s not continue this discussion in comments :P

Comment: Oh, okay. Nice blog btw