# You Can't See Me Coz I'm NOT John Cena!

Tags: riddle, wordplay, enigmatic-puzzle, rhyme, knowledge

> As a pack, we pursue the pity, for power, on the flee.
>
> As a king, I was a clashing knight, couldn't you see?
>
> As a wolf, I am white without any whispers;
>
> And just for fun, I'm first fish, then first.

What am I?

---

HINTS:

Title:

> I'm not in any related to John, but we do have something similar. Can't you see it?

Massive hint:

> Just bust it!

Lines:

> /f///
> C<...
> GT"Sh..."
> CR!!!

Comment: I have a feeling this has to do with movies that John Cena is in...  Like how he is a bigfoot in "Littlefoot" and you can't see them unless you're very lucky

Comment: Nah, That's just a pun, I'll add a hint ;) @YoutRied

Comment: This question is great!!

Comment: Your answer is also great! @H_D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are:

> Ghost.

Title:

> You can't see John Cena and you also can't see a ghost.

As a pack, we pursue the pity, for power, on the flee.

> Pac(k) ==> pacman ( C<... --> graphics of the game pacman)
> When the pacman eats the power pellet, the ghosts flee as the pacman has the power to eat the ghosts.

As a king, I was a clashing knight, couldn't you see?

> In Clash Royale (CR), the king is not able to see the royal ghost.
> The royal ghost deals a lot of damage, therefore is referred to as a clashing knight.

As a wolf, I am white without any whispers;

> Game of Thrones (GT)
> In Game of Thrones, the character Jon owns a wolf which is white in color named Ghost.
> Also, Ghost moves around very quietly, matching the criteria without any whispers.

And just for fun, I'm first fish, then first.

> [Ghotiy spelling](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/32278/ghotiy-spelling)
> An alternate and unusual spelling of fish is ghoti.
> First merged with ghoti is ghost.
> /f/ is pronounced as ffff, first sound of fish.

Just bust it!

> Ever heard of The Ghostbusters? (A movie)

Comment: Nice job! You got it! also clashing refers to the game as well

Comment: Thanks! I worked on it for a long time!

Answer (score 5):

Is the answer

> Alliteration?

As a pack, we pursue the pity, for power, on the flee.

> *pack*, *pursue*, *pity*, *power*, begin with a [p] consonant sound.

As a king, I was a clashing knight, couldn't you see?

> *king*, *clashing*, *couldn’t*, begin with a /k/ consonant sound.

As a wolf, I am white without any whispers;

> *wolf*, *white*, *without*, *whispers*, begin with a [w] consonant sound.

And just for fun, I’m first fish, then first.

> *for*, *fun*, *first*, *fish*, *first*, begin with a /f/ consonant sound.

Comment: Nice try, but not quite yet! Keep it up ;)

Comment: In fact I am using the technique in your answer deliberately just to make the riddle more poetic. Read the content to get to the answer. Enjoy puzzling:)

Comment: @OmegaKrypton Of course! I should have guessed it.